# Expressing sum of sine and cosine functions as a single functions

Tags: trigonometry

I am currently struggling to understand the rationale behind the concept of combining two different cosine and sine functions into a single one using graphical method(right triangle graph).Eg: $a \sin x + b \cos x = r[\cos (x- b)] $  Can somebody show/explain it to me?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the graphical method to be used? Also, please expand your example - is $b$ the same parameter appearing twice?

Comment: Sry for being unclear.The graphical method is like the one shown in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qRM07xs99Q).And for the second question,No,they are not the same parameter appearing twice.It's just a typo,hence it should be another variable instead of b.

Answer (score 0):

Construct a right triangle with hypotenuse $a$ and angle $x$
and a similar triangle with hypotenuse $b$ rotated 90 degrees as in the figure.

[image]

But notice that $a,b$ forms the legs of a different right triangle.

[image]

This triangle has hypotenuse $\sqrt {a^2+b^2}$ and angle $\arctan \frac {b}{a}$

And this triangle.

[image]

Has hypotenuse $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2},$ angle $(x-\arctan \frac {b}{a})$ and adjacent side $a\cos x + b\sin x$

Comment: Woahhhh great illustration.I believe I understand the concept now.Just need a while to digest it myself.Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: HI again.May I know why is the third triangle has an angle of $ (x - arch\tan b/a) $ ? I could only illustrate an image where the angle of the red triangle is $ (arch\tan b/a - x) $ as $ (arch\tan b/a) $ is greater than $ x $

Comment: "negative angles" are angles that move in a clockwise direction and positive angles move in a counterclockwise direction.  This is purely convention and you could define them the opposite way around.  Nonetheless, the sign corresponds to direction.  However, since cosine is an even function, that is $\cos (-x) = \cos x$ it doesn't really matter.  i.e. $a\cos x + b\sin x = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2} \cos (x-\arctan \frac ba) =  \sqrt {a^2 + b^2} \cos (\arctan \frac ba - x)$

Comment: Ohhhh  I was thinking about the properties of cosine function where both negative and positive angles contribute to a same answer.Thank you for letiing me know that.